# How to sort an array of alphanumeric file names in ascending order?

Tags: c#

I have an array of string of .sql files directory that I need to sort in ascending order. Actually I want to sort it based on numeric part, if no numeric part then file should come on top.
How can I do this?

```
3.5.1_Patch

3.5_CoreScript

3.6_Patch

3.6.1_Patch
```

Comment: yes, I did you but not sure on this alphanumeric part..

Comment: You should show what you tried or your question will get down voted for lack of effort and likely closed.  Also you should give details about exactly how you want your sorting to work.  I assume you want to sort on the version like numbers before the underscore and then the text after, but what if there is a file without the version numbers, would that come first or last?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should make you question as specific as possible. You can do what you want using `Array.Sort` and a lambda function:

```
string [] files = new string[] {"3.6.1_Patch","3.5_CoreScript","3.5.1_Patch","3.6_Patch"};
Array.Sort(files, (x,y) => {
    string [] x1 = x.Split('_');
    string [] y1 = y.Split('_');
    return String.Compare(x1[0], y1[0]);
});
```

I left it to you to handle the edge case where there is no version number.

**EDIT**

Your file names are more complex than originally presented. I'll assume everything up to the first non-numeric string is the version?

At this point I would make a class to parse the filenames and store the version numbers. It also implements the `IComparable` interface for sorting.

```
public class Version : IComparable<Version> {
    // Just guessing here - without knowing the actual format
    public int Major = 0;
    public int Minor = 0;
    public int Build = 0;
    public string FileName;

    public Version(string fileName) {
        ParseFileName(fileName);
    }

    // Split the string on '_' or '.',
    // Considers the first 3 numbers to be version
    // (stops parsing at non-numeric value)
    public void ParseFileName(string fileName) 
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        string [] data = Regex.Split(fileName, @"[_\.]");
        int x;
        if (Int32.TryParse(data[0], out x)) {
            Major = x;
            if (2 <= data.Length && Int32.TryParse(data[1], out x)) {
                Minor = x;
                if (3 <= data.Length && Int32.TryParse(data[2], out x)) {
                    Build = x;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return FileName;
    }

    // Comparison
    public int CompareTo(Version v) {
        int c = Major.CompareTo(v.Major);
        if (0 == c) {
            c = Minor.CompareTo(v.Minor);
        }
        if (0 == c) {
            c = Build.CompareTo(v.Build);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
string [] files = new string[] {"10.6.1_Patch","3.5_CoreScript","3.5.1_Patch","3.6_Patch","10.6_Patch", "test", "01_1_ALTER_TC_EDB_V3", "01_2_ALTER_TC_EDB_V3"};
Version [] versions = new Version[files.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
    versions[i] = new Version(files[i]);
}
Array.Sort(versions);
foreach (var v in versions) {
    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
test
01_1_ALTER_TC_EDB_V3
01_2_ALTER_TC_EDB_V3
3.5_CoreScript
3.5.1_Patch
3.6_Patch
10.6_Patch
10.6.1_Patch
```

Comment: This will say that 2 is greater than 10.

Comment: @Servy True. Will fix.....

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if there are more than one _ involved how would I sort?
like 01_1_ALTER_TC_EDB_V3, 01_2_ALTER_TC_EDB_V3

Comment: You're going to need a bit more advanced parsing. What is the version string in your example?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> input = new List<string>() { "3.5.1_Patch", "3.5_CoreScript", "3.6_Patch", "3.6.1_Patch" };


            input.Sort((x,y) => new CustomSort() { s = x}.CompareTo(y));
        }
    }

    public class CustomSort : IComparable
    {
        public string s { get; set; }
        public int CompareTo(object input)
        {
            string[] thissplitArray = (s).Split(new char[] { '_' }).ToArray();
            string[] splitArray = ((string)input).Split(new char[] { '_' }).ToArray();

            if (thissplitArray[0] == splitArray[0])
            {
                return thissplitArray[1].CompareTo(splitArray[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                return thissplitArray[0].CompareTo(splitArray[0]);
            }

        }
    }


}
```